# Adding checkbox beside row

Tags: php, html

I have searched the internet but I but seem to find exactly what I am looking for I am trying to add a check box beside each row in a table

```
    <?php
echo"<table border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' class='tableClassToConvert' height='472' width='734'>";
    echo"<thead>";
                echo"<tr>";
            echo"<th scope='col' style='width: 429px;'>Registration of a Company</th>";
            echo"<th scope='col' style='width: 171px;'>ZMK</th>";
            echo"<th scope='col' style='width: 140px;'>(US$)</th>";
        echo"</tr>";
    echo"</thead>";
    echo"<tbody>";
        echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td style='width: 429px;'><strong>Private Company with Minimum Nominal Capital of K10,000 (U$1450)</strong></td>";
            echo"<td style=''width: 171px;'>&nbsp;</td>";
            echo"<td style='width: 140px;'>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        echo"<tr>";           
            echo"<input type='checkbox'/> <td style='width: 429px;'>Registration Fee (2.5 percent of Minimum Nominal Capital)    </td>";
            echo"<td class='tableCellToConvert' style='width: 171px;'>250</td>";
            echo"<td style='width: 140px;'>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
</table>
?>
```

When I ran that code the check box is going outside the table on the top. What I am trying to do is add the check box outside the table but besides the row how can I achieve this.

Comment: Your inputs needs an opening <TD> tag   .....  You have just TR INPUT TD TR on that row

Comment: Furthermore, I would recommend that you code the HTML directly, instead of echoing it out. That'll make it easier to spot mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely have to put the checkboxes inside a td on each row, then style the table and rows to make it *look* like the Registration column is the first row of the table.